# Изменить доступность товара на сайте при условии отсутствия товара на складе магазина(типовой обмен 1с с битрикс)

Tags: битрикс, 1с

Поставили задачу, сделать так, что бы при условии когда остаток товара в магазине был равен 0, сайт подставлял остатки товара поставщика и кнопка "купить" изменялась на кнопку "под заказ"

Настроен типовой обмен 1с с битрикс, он передает все, что нужно и товар со всеми ценами и остатками отображается корректно, как сделать так, чтоб сайт замещал остатки магазина на остатки поставщика?

Я совсем новичок в битрикс и не понимаю пока куда мне стоит копать, помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Нужно кастомизировать шаблон компонента списка элементов каталога `catalog.section`, который используется в комплексном компоненте `catalog` документация по самому компоненту: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/content/catalog/catalog_section.php

Вот документация по кастомизации шаблона: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=4778